# (simple) linux HA with vmware vsphere?

Tags: virtualization, vmware-vsphere, high-availability, opensuse

I hope my upcoming question is specific enough, and you are able and willing to support :-)
We have several openSUSE VMs in an ESX-Cluster (three ESX-Servers) with an attached iSCSI-SAN.

All of those Linux VMs are "single point of failure"-configured, which means in the case of a Web-Server: LAMP, storage, etc. everything on this machine.
This was very simple and in case of a failure (in the last years: kernel panics or apache crashes) a simple reboot triggered by a script did it.

But the problem is: How to upgrade/maintain the w(eb-)application or the underlying OS without downtime? This wasn't really managable and i did this in the early morning ;)
How can i achieve a "simple" High-Availability Cluster now?

I thought of: DRBD with heartbeat with 2 VMs. And for the storage a RDM (raw device mapped) LUN and change the read-write-permissions for both VMs.

Is this a good idea? Anyone has a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you want some degree of HA for the web or app servers then just use a load-balancer of some form, but for HA on the database then yes you probably want to cluster that in some way. That said I'm no fan of RDMs, they cause as many problems as they fix but that's all you need to do.

Comment: i don't like to use the term load-balancer because in my case there is no overload... Thats why i wanted to use DRBD with heartbeat with a virtual IP.